# Passing relative function pointers as parameters

Tags: c++, pointers, stdvector, std-function

Say I have a namespace `KeyManager` and I have the function `press`

```
std::vector<std::function<void()>*> functions;

void KeyManager::addFunction(std::function<void()> *listener)
{
    functions.push_back(listener);
}

void KeyManager::callFunctions()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < functions.size(); ++i)
    {
        // Calling all functions in the vector:
        (*functions[i])();
    }
}
```

and I have class `Car` and in the constructor of car I want to pass it's **relative** function pointer to a class function like so:

```
void Car::printModel()
{
    fprintf(stdout, "%s", this->model.c_str());
}

Car::Car(std::string model)
{
    this->model = model;
    KeyManager::addFunction(this->printModel);
}
```

I get the following error when trying to pass the relative function pointer:

```
error C3867: 'Car::printModel': function call missing argument list; use '&Car::printModel' to create a pointer to member
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you please provide the code for "Car::testKey" I didn't find it in the post.

Comment: Sorry I copy and pasted the error from my production code and forgot to rename it for the example.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `std::bind` to create an `std::function` that invokes a member function on a specific object. This is how that works:

```
Car::Car(std::string model)
{
    this->model = model;
    KeyManager::addFunction(std::bind(&Car::printModel, this));
}
```

Is there a specific reason why you are passing the `std::function` as pointer, instead of a value? If you are not binding any arguments that are expensive to copy, I would rather not do that.

Also, `callFunctions` can be simplified using a lambda:

```
void KeyManager::callFunctions() 
{
    for (auto & f : functions) 
        f();
}
```

Comment: It can be simplified further with a ranged for loop: `for (auto & f : functions) f();`

Comment: Ha, still haven't gotten used to all this new C++11 stuff.

Comment: I need to pass a pointer to an std::function... not the function itself.

Comment: `std::bind` creates a wrapper that stores a pointer to a function and all the arguments that you bind. This wrapper is then stored in an `std::function`. There is really no reason to use a pointer here.

Comment: I'm getting an error using this: `error C2664: 'void KeyManager::press(int,std::function<void (void)> *)' : cannot convert argument 2 from 'std::_Bind<true,void,std::_Pmf_wrap<void (__thiscall Car::* )(void),void,Car,>,Car *const >' to 'std::function<void (void)> *'`

It's because I'm passing a pointer I wanted to pass a pointer in case at any point I needed to remove it from the vector.

Comment: I do not know your full code, but once again, don't use a pointer here. You can remove the function from the vector even if it is not a pointer.